# How to put an image on Google Map using Api v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple image of house(top view, looks like a 3d model) and I want to place this picture of the house on place where this house stands (on roadmap). [This is  an example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIJNF.png). But I have a big problem with position, I just can't place the image correctly, it's torn or drives off ([an example of what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu29I.png)).
I read all documentation about overlays but I don't know how to make this thing, maybe somebody tell me how to do it or show the direction where to go?

Example of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ground Overlays</title>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>

var Overlay;

function initialize() {

var house = new google.maps.LatLng(55.734907, 37.571526);
var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(55.734603,37.571374),
  new google.maps.LatLng(55.734944,37.572097),
  new google.maps.LatLng(55.735032,37.571221),
  new google.maps.LatLng(55.735201,37.570343),
  new google.maps.LatLng(55.735218,37.570840),
  new google.maps.LatLng(55.735238,37.571670),
  new google.maps.LatLng(55.735423,37.571147),
  new google.maps.LatLng(55.735551,37.570891)  
  );

 var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 17,
 center: house,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

 Overlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
  'file:///home/map_top.png',
  imageBounds);
 Overlay.setMap(map);
 }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

     </script>
    </head>
   <body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem could be your bounds. Use only two points the SouthWest and the NorthEst corners of the rectangle. 

`LatLngBounds(sw?:LatLng, ne?:LatLng)`

Try changing one of this points (sw) until your reach the right position.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer but is there different way to reach what I want? May be these guys that made such interesting thing(first example) used another method?

Comment: Could you upload the image _map_top.png_ to try something please

Comment: Which exemple are you talking about? This one: [Simple GroudOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple)

Comment: Sorry, may be you got me wrong, I'm talking about [this](http://i.imgur.com/5Lbka7v.png) example. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/JvlcpdV.png) map_top.png

Comment: So basically the code your put here is an exemple from elsewhere and what they achived is [this](http://i.imgur.com/5Lbka7v.png)and with the same code what you achived is [this](http://i.imgur.com/0ySu1px.png)?

Comment: Code that I put here, is an [example from google api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/groundoverlay-simple), almost full copy and I only know that these guys used this technique but I don't know how exactly they have achieved such a [result](http://i.imgur.com/5Lbka7v.png) so I'm asking about this, may be someone did something similar and can help.

Comment: So, what do you think about this?

Comment: I will put an example as answer. You have to calculate your bounds so the anchor point is the one you want. I will explain that in the answer!

Comment: In the exemple of google they do the same way, there is no other _techique_

Comment: So, did you get over of this?
Did you get a look at my answer (with the last edited code)?

Comment: I did, thank you. I have already noted your answer as correct but I want to ask you one more little question. Your code shows only the longitude of anchor points without latitude, it's because the latitude is stable, right?

Comment: it shows the longitude in the labels you mean?

Comment: I show only the longitude in the labels because what I was doing was moving horizontally the image so only variating the longitudes. 
Then I edited the code to re-size the image an therefore I'm variating the longitude and latitude of NE point but I did not show this latitude in a label.

Comment: Yes. I ask because if I set two coordinates, that I found with your code (e.g (55.734603, 37.570573), (55.734944, 37.571896)),  image looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/3BVafzj.png) although in constructor everything is [okay](http://i.imgur.com/CrU0x9u.png)

Comment: You can variate the bounds watching the proportions of your image if not it is deformated as you found. For example if your image is a rectangle of 25x20 your bounds have to have the same proportion so you can made a rectangle of 20x16 but not a rectangle of 21x19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The anchor is located along the center point of the bottom of the* 'bounds' (image) (You can see that [here, Icon being an overlay too like GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) you can safely infer that that apply also to GroundOverlay.

Therefore your bounds has to be calculated to account this.

Besides, the constructor for `google.maps.LatLngBounds` take only 2 points. In your case the two firsts points:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(55.734603,37.571374)
new google.maps.LatLng(55.734944,37.572097)
```

If you pass more points they will be ignored.

Note that the coordinates in the format google.maps take is of this form DD.mmmmmm, so the part after the point are meters (if my memory does not disappoint me). Therefore if your image is at scale you can easily calculate your anchor point.

In the following example I worked with your two firsts points. To get it to work:

1. Copy all the code in a .html file
2. Change the path of the image.
3. Run the page.

Then you can move to the right and to the left your image to demonstrate what I'm saying.

--- EDITED CODE: add the functions to make the image smaller/bigger ---------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Ground Overlays</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="step" value="100" />
            <button id="left">Left</button>
            <button id="right">Right</button>
            <button id="smaller">Smaller</button>
            <button id="bigger">Bigger</button>
            <label id="lng0">0</label>
            <label id="lng1">1</label>
        </div>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        <script>

            var stepPresition = 1000000.0;
            var Overlay;
            var markers = [];
            var map;
            var coordinates = [{ lat: 55.734603, lng: 37.571374 }, { lat: 55.734944, lng: 37.572097 }];
            var points;


            function initialize() {

                var house = new google.maps.LatLng(55.734907, 37.571526);

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 17,
                    center: house,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

                AddOverlay();
                SetLabels();
            }

            function RemoveMarkers() {

                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    markers[i].setMap(null);
                }
                markers = [];
            }

            function AddOverlay() {

                points = [new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[0].lat, coordinates[0].lng),
                           new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[1].lat, coordinates[1].lng)];

                for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({ position: points[i], map: map, title: "Marker " + i }));
                }

                var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(points[0], points[1]);

                Overlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay('Content/images/map_top.png', imageBounds);
                Overlay.setMap(map);
            }
            function RemoveOverlay() {
                Overlay.setMap(null);
                Overlay = null;
            }

            function MoveTo(step) {
                for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
                    coordinates[i].lng = coordinates[i].lng + step;
                }
                RemoveMarkers();
                RemoveOverlay();
                AddOverlay();
                SetLabels();
            }
            function MoveToLeft() {
                var step = parseFloat($("#step").val() / stepPresition);
                MoveTo((-1) * step);
            }
            function MoveToRight() {
                var step = parseFloat($("#step").val() / stepPresition);
                MoveTo(step);
            }
            function SizeTo(step) {

                coordinates[1].lng = coordinates[1].lng + step;
                coordinates[1].lat = coordinates[1].lat + step;

                RemoveMarkers();
                RemoveOverlay();
                AddOverlay();
                SetLabels();
            }
            function SizeToSW() {
                var step = parseFloat($("#step").val() / stepPresition);
                SizeTo((-1) * step);
            }
            function SizeToNE() {
                var step = parseFloat($("#step").val() / stepPresition);
                SizeTo(step);
            }
            function SetLabels() {
                var lng0 = $("#lng0"), lng1 = $("#lng1");

                lng0.html("SW Point Longitude: " + parseInt(coordinates[0].lng * stepPresition) / stepPresition);
                lng1.html("NE Point Longitude: " + parseInt(coordinates[1].lng * stepPresition) / stepPresition);
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#left").on('click', function () {
                    MoveToLeft();
                });
                $("#right").on('click', function () {
                    MoveToRight();
                });
                $("#smaller").on('click', function () {
                    SizeToSW();
                });
                $("#bigger").on('click', function () {
                    SizeToNE();
                });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this help you.

NOTE: The code is only for demostrate my point, is not the best performing and proper way to do what I've done here.

Comment: Thank you very much sabotero, but what do you think about why the picture is so small in contrast with [example](http://i.imgur.com/5Lbka7v.png) from these guys?

Comment: It's because of the bounds too!
Your bounds (defined by the SW and NE point) makes a rectangle. If your rectangle is small the image will be small.

Comment: Change the value in the text box for _go quickly_ in moving or resizing the image.